# Access string from dictionary value in Python

Tags: python

I am trying to write a comprehension that, given two dictionaries (f, g), will return a dictionary whose key is the key of f, and whose value is the corresponding key's value of f of the value of g. For example, given:

```
f = {0: 'a', 1: 'b'}
g = {'a': 'apple', 'b': 'banana'}
my_function_composition(f, g) #returns {0: 'apple', 1: 'banana'}
```

My comprehension for some reason only outputs one character of the string

```
#output: {0: 'e', 1: 'a'}
```

Here is my function:

```
def my_function_composition(f, g):
    return {key: value for key in f for value in g[f[key]]}
```

Why is Python returning what seems to be the last character of the value string, rather than the entire string?

Comment: Notice how it’s the *last* character, and think about what `for value in g[f[key]]` means.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
def my_function_composition(f, g):
    return {key: g[value] for key, value in f.items()}
```

To be safer you can use `g.get(value, 0)` in case `g` doesn't have that key and you want a default value like `0`.

In case you need only the `f` values that are in `g` dictionary you can add extra check for the `value`.

```
def my_function_composition(f, g):
    return {key: g[value] for key, value in f.items() if value in g}
```

Comment: Didin't see this before I posted my solution

Answer (score 0):

```
def my_function_composition(f, g):
    return {key1: value2 for key1, value1 in f for key2, value2 in g if value1==key2}
```

Answer (score 0):

`{key : g.get(f[key], None) for key in f}` Compatible with both python 3 and 2